# Migrating mailboxes from EXCH 2007 to EXCH 2010 based on message class

Tags: exchange, powershell, mailbox, migration

Is it possible through a powershell command to migrate mailboxes with the option of ignoring particular message classes, or even better, is there an option to ignore specific ones (ie. Inbox IPM.Note)

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

No, only export requests can be content filtered

Like this:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607299.aspx

Use the -ContentFilter parameter to specify for instance ($_.MessageClass -ne "IPM.Note") to ignore these messages

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I where to export it what the commandlet for content filtering? ie Post or Notes. Thanks

Comment: @Carlos: just updated the post with some info (only available in Exchange 2010)